# SOQL query filter by value of another column

Tags: apex, soql, query, filters

I am trying to make an extremely simple query where I filter the result based on the result of two columns.

Ex:

```
SELECT x, y FROM coordinates WHERE x > y;
```

So far I didn't found any example of how to compare dynamic fields in a SOQL filter query. The result is: Unknown error parsing query.

Any idea of how to do it on SOQL?

Comment: I've linked a related question and answer that addresses your question. However, please note that you can compare fields [in a report](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_rd_reports_filter_field_to_field.htm), which may get you want you want.

Comment: The report doesn't help me, but the formula field does. I don't understand why I need to create a new database field just to make a simple comparison. But thank you for your answer.

Comment: Up until that release, we always had to use formulas, there was no basic SQL-like comparison of fields. Hopefully someday this will work in SOQL, too, but for now, you can build a report and use the [ReportManager](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_reports_reportmanager.htm) methods to get the data out of a report you built with these filters.

Comment: I am using SOQL inside my apex code to use the data inside my logic, I am not making a report. But the formula field inside the Object will help me. Cheers